# Data Types with XML Nodes in VBA Excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am using createTextNode to create string nodes for a macro that exports excel data to an XML. How do I create Nodes of other Data Types? When I use this on numbers it add a 1 after all my numbers.eg. If I put amount 50 in snip below the xml outputs 501.

Below is a sample of what I have: (I would like Amount to be Data Type double).

```
Do While .Cells(Data_Row, 4).Value <> "" 
    Set oProcessI = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "ProcessInput", "")
    oFor.appendChild oProcessI
    Set oIng = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "Ingredient", "")
    oIng.appendChild oXMLDoc.createTextNode(.Cells(Data_Row, 4).Value)
    oProcessI.appendChild oIng
    Set oAmount = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "Amount", "")
    oAmount.appendChild oXMLDoc.createTextNode(.Cells(Data_Row, 5).Value)
    oProcessI.appendChild oAmount
    Set oUOM = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "UOM", "")
    oUOM.appendChild oXMLDoc.createTextNode(.Cells(Data_Row, 6).Value)
    oProcessI.appendChild oUOM
    Set oSeq = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "SeqNumber", "")
    oAmount.appendChild oXMLDoc.createTextNode("1")
    oProcessI.appendChild oSeq

    Data_Row = Data_Row + 1
Loop
```

Additionally is there one for a date data type?

Thanks!

Comment: consider this: and XML file is just a text document. It's up to the parser to determine datatype, sometimes enforced by an XSD or xml schema. The short story is: everything is text in the XML world!

Comment: Ohh I see. Well then should I put everything in my excel in test formate so it doesn't add a 1 after all my numbers? Although I did want my excel to do some summations that will not work with text.

Comment: "should I put everything in my excel in text format": No, definitely not! You need to understand what the code does and not adding text nodes to elements to which they not belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set oSeq = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "SeqNumber", "")
oAmount.appendChild oXMLDoc.createTextNode("1")
oProcessI.appendChild oSeq
```

should probably be

```
Set oSeq = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "SeqNumber", "")
oSeq.appendChild oXMLDoc.createTextNode("1")
oProcessI.appendChild oSeq
```

You're adding the text node to the wrong element

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Silly me :)